# How to combine only overlapping parts of multiple shapefile layers?

Tags: qgis

I have 5 shapefiles. 4 of roads and one of 3 adjoining cities. How can I combine somehow the areas where the street and the cities shapefiles overlap, omitting streets not lying in those cities? The colored areas in the lower left are the cities. [image]

Comment: Most of the functions under vector geoprocessing.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in your final result? What is the end goal?

Comment: What I am trying to do is remove all the roads which lie outside the shaded areas.

Answer (score 2):

Merge the 4 roads files into a single shapefile. Then clip this layer with the cities polygon file. The result will be all the roads within the boundaries of the 3 cities.